# make jquery chosen plugin work with dynamically added dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

Ok so I have an app that adds a new dropdown element to the dom on click, but because the new dropdown is added after chosen is instantiated `$('.dropdowns').chosen()` it's not turned into a chosen dropdown.

Is there a better way to make dynamically created dropdowns work without having to re-instantiate jquery version of chosen (i.e. without having to re-call `$('.dropdowns').chosen()`)?

Comment: Can't you just call the chosen plugin on the added select on the click event?

Comment: you mean `$('#dropdown').chosen()` ?

Comment: Can you create your new dropdown as a `clone()` of an existing one?  See:  http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: nah cloning at this point in the app would require a great deal of refactoring

Answer (score 0):

you can simply recall chosen plugin after inserting the dynamic dropdown

```
/*

 code of creating dynamic dropdown

after it add:
*/

$('#ID_OF_DYNAMIC_DROPDOWN').chosen();
```

in my case i use:

```
var i=$('#table_invoice tbody tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';

    html += '<td><select name="item_id[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control searchable chosen-rtl">'+ItemOptions+'</select></td>';

    html += '</tr>';

    $('#table_invoice').append(html);
    $('#itemName_'+i).chosen(); 
    i++;
});
```